# How do I access an object associated with a Parse.User?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

What I want to do is query for every `Parse.User` whose `MComparisonArray` object hasn't been updated on today's date.

Below is what I've got so far, a mix of regular and psuedo-code. This doesn't work, and gives the error `ReferenceError: updatedAt is not defined`.

I think the issue is that I'm not referencing the MComparisonArray object correctly, but I can't seem to find anything in the [docs](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/) that could point me in the right direction.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("MatchCenterBackground", function(request, status) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    var usersQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    usersQuery.greaterThan(Parse.User.MComparisonArray, updatedAt);

    return usersQuery.each(function(user) {
            return processUser(user)
                .then(function(eBayResults) {
                    return matchCenterComparison(user, eBayResults);
                });
        })
        .then(function() {
            // Set the job's success status
            status.success("MatchCenterBackground completed successfully.");
        }, function(error) {
            // Set the job's error status
            status.error("Got an error " + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
});
```

Comment: Is `updatedAt` defined?

Comment: @Oleander updatedAt is a default Parse column

Comment: You are in effect trying to compare the object MComparisonArray with updatedAt (which in your code seems to be a variable). Create two queries. First query should be on the MComparisonArray object and fetches all objects that have updatedAt < today. Then use this query in your second query (on Parse.User), matching on the MComparisonArray. See more info here: https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#queries-relational-queries